# passing jslt value to javascript

Tags: jstl

I trying to a pass a jslt value to javascript but the value is not getting rendered.

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.P.Releases}" var="pr" varStatus="status">     <a href=javascript:popPR('${pr.url}') class="linkPR">
     <c:out value="${pr.title}" escapeXml='false' /></a>
<c:foreach>
```

if directly type the pr.url value the popup window gets opened but if i pass the through jstl it does not call the popup.

Can anyone please suggest how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<c:out>` to output the url :

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.P.Releases}" var="pr" varStatus="status">     
<a href=javascript:popPR('<c:out value="${pr.url}"/>') class="linkPR">
     <c:out value="${pr.title}" escapeXml='false' /></a>
<c:foreach>
```